# Send POST request to Wordpress to make a new post

Tags: posts

I want to make new posts on my Wordpress blog using HTTP POST sent to `post.php`. I was searching for the parameters I should pass but i didn't find any useful information yet. Can anyone give me a reference to the parameters I should send?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using XML-RPC. You can find the documentation [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_Support). This is a more mature and secure approach than building your own functionality that already exists in core.

You can find all of the methods for various operations [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API).